# How to apply formatting to an object properties in an array?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Powershell script that extracts some email properties from a database and displays them in a tabular format. I've been able to format the actual data easy enough, but as I'm using the object's attributes as a header, I'm struggling trying to apply formatting to them (ie, bold or underline HTML tags).

I've tried modifying the actual attributes as I call them (ie, in line 2) but as the object doesn't contain any attributes like **Domain** that fails. And I know I can't apply the formatting to the assignment lines, as then it wouldn't be able to compile (ie,  "some html + $Result.'Service Location' + "/ some html")

My code sample is as follows...

```
 foreach($email in $api_call.data){
            $Result = "" | Select Type, Domains, 'Service Location', 'Webmail URL', 'SPF-Enabled' 
            $Result.Type = $email.attributes.traits.'type' + "<br>"
            $Result.Domains = $email.attributes.traits.'domain-s'.values.name + "<br>"
            $Result.'Service Location' = $email.attributes.traits.'service-location' + "<br>"
            $Result.'Webmail URL' = $email.attributes.traits.'webmail-url' + "<br>"
            $Result.'SPF-Enabled' = $email.attributes.traits.'spf-enabled' + "<br>"
            $Array += $Result
```

My goal is output like so:

HTML Type /HTML          : Office 365
HTML Domains  /HTML           : somedomain
HTML Service Location /HTML  : Cloud
HTML Webmail URL /HTML       : https://outlook.office.com/owa/
HTML SPF-Enabled /HTML      :

Can anyone give me some ideas of how to achieve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Add new atributes to the object for the formatting then use them when you need to output? e.g.$Result.WebmailUrlFormat = "bold"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using PowerShell Custom Object?

```
$Result = foreach($email in $api_call.data){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Type = $email.attributes.traits.'type' + "<br>"
        Domains = $email.attributes.traits.'domain-s'.values.name + "<br>"
        'Service Location' = $email.attributes.traits.'service-location' + "<br>"
        'Webmail URL' = $email.attributes.traits.'webmail-url' + "<br>"
        'SPF-Enabled' = $email.attributes.traits.'spf-enabled' + "<br>"
    }
}
```

Thre result would be stored as a collection into the $Result variable, they you may format it as a table: `$Result | format-table -autosize` or export it as CSV: `$Result | Export-CSV -path C:\SomeDir\FileName.csv` for example.

Note: I am not sure what the variables contain or what values you would like to input, but this is the syntax for using PSCustomObject. 
Also you may check the article, for a better understanding: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6

Hope it helps!